# Trial software for Lotus Notes client server scenario

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I'm in a software project and need to take care of a component that connects to a Lotus Notes server in order to create users, assign authorization groups etc.

I would like to configure a basic client / server scenario on my own hardware to familiarize with the Notes technology but I have only found trial versions for client software components like Domino Designer. I would expect that a Domino server is also required.

Does anybody know whether. and if yes, how I can get the required server components? Or is it required to purchase a license?

Many thanks in advance for every reply.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a trial of IBM Domino here:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/downloads/ls/lsds/

Comment: Is there a free option for Amazon EC2 or IBM cloud servers for developers? I think there might have been at one time, but I've lost track.

Answer (score 0):

http://dominodeveloper.net offers a free development server option that I have used successfully in the past. Always worked well for me.